# C# Code takes to long to run. Is there a way to make it finish quicker?

Tags: c#, multithreading, recursion, subdirectory

I need some help. If you input an Directory into my code, it goes in every folder in that Directory and gets every single file. This way, i managed to bypass the "AccessDeniedException" by using a code, BUT if the Directory is one, which contains alot of Data and folders (example: C:/) it just takes way to much time.

I dont really know how to multithread and i could not find any help on the internet.  Is there a way to make the code run faster by multithreading?  Or is it possible to ask the code to use more memory or Cores ? I really dont know and could use advise

My code to go in every File in every Subdirectory:

```
public static List<string> Files = new List<string>();
public static List<string> Exceptions = new List<string>();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private static void GetFilesRecursively(string Directory)
{
    try
    {
         foreach (string A in Directory.GetDirectories(Directory))
             GetFilesRecursively(A);

         foreach (string B in Directory.GetFiles(Directory))
             AddtoList(B);

    } catch (System.Exception ex) { Exceptions.Add(ex.ToString()); }
}

private static void AddtoList(string Result)
{
    Files.Add(Result);
}

private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GetFilesRecursively(Textbox1.Text);
    
    foreach(string C in Files)
       Textbox2.Text += $"{C} \n";
}
```

Comment: Scanning your entire hard drive is going to take time, however you go about it. Even applications whose whole purpose is to do this, such as WinDirStat, take a long time to do it.

Comment: How many items `Exceptions` contains? Letting exception to occurs is the last resort, especially if you are talking about performance. Rather you have to prevent exceptions, e.g by checking folder rights before trying to access it.

Comment: What is the purpose of your code? To get a list of files from a directory and its subdirectories you have access to or does it matter if you get the exceptions as well? As you can call GetFiles on a directory and include subdirectories as well, by passing the search option AllDirectories into the GetFiles call.

Comment: Do you really need the result of the complete folder before you can start? If I think of a visual tree for example it would be enough to load expanded nodes (on demand).

Comment: Why are you using recursion instead of eg `Directory.EnumerateFiles` or `Directory.FileSystemEntries` with recursion? If you want to avoid inaccessible files you can set [EnumerationOptions.IgnoreInaccessible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.enumerationoptions.ignoreinaccessible?view=net-5.0) to `true`

Comment: You could get a list of directories inside the first directory, split it in, say, 3 different lists and have 3 threads go over the lists in parallel using recursion. The problem is that this may lead to race conditions, depending on what you want to do with the data. If the sequence doesn't matter this might be a good approach. However if your objective is to do something with the files, you will probably need a way to synchronize the threads. Maybe it would be helpful to know what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: @AsPas: When reading file systems CPU isn't your problem in most cases. And file systems tend to get slower the more processes access it in parallel.

Comment: @Klamsi I agree. That's why I am asking him what his objective is. If his objective is to learn about multithreading and he wants to specifically do this with multithreading, it is possible but as I said only for very basic things like printing filenames would this make sense. If you actually have to open files, write to them or anything else, multi threading would be useless and in fact lower performance.

Comment: @Klamsi  Me and a Friend of mine are just learning to Code. Now we found out that, if we use the EnumerateFiles Code with  - RecursiveSubdirectories - in the Console. It Works just fine.   But if we try it with WPF, the RecurisveSubdirectories code wont work. So i found this method. My Goal is to List every possible single file that is on the path i enter.

Comment: @RPT: the question is how you want to display the files. If you use a Tree wherre the user expands nodes manually there are much faster possibilities.

Comment: @Klamsi No, thats not the goal. The goal is really just to list all of the Files with the path. Like: 

c:/Users/Username/Pictures/Picturefile1.jpg
c:/Users/Username/Pictures/PictureFile2.jpg
etc.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need recursion to avoid inaccessible files. You can use the [EnumerateFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=net-5.0#System_IO_Directory_EnumerateFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_EnumerationOptions_) overload that accepts an [EnumerationOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.enumerationoptions?view=net-5.0) parameter and set [EnumerationOptions.IgnoreInaccessible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.enumerationoptions.ignoreinaccessible?view=net-5.0) to `true`:

```
var options=new EnumerationOptions 
            {
                IgnoreInaccessible=true,
                RecurseSubdirectories=true
            };
var files=Directory.EnumerateFiles(somePath,"*",options);
```

The *loop* that appends file paths is very expensive too. Not only does it create a new temporary string on each iteration, it also forces a UI redraw. You could improve speed and memory usage (which, due to garbage collection is also affecting performance) by creating a single string, eg with `String.Join` or a `StringBuilder` :

```
var text=String.Join("\n",files);
Textbox2.Text=text;
```

`String.Join` uses a StringBuilder internally whose internal buffer gets reallocated each time it's full. The previous buffer has to be garbage-collected. Once could avoid even this by using a `StringBuilder` with a specific capacity. Even a rough estimate can reduce reallocations significantly:

```
var builder=new StringBuilder(4096);
foreach(var file in files)
{
    builder.AppendLine(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. create a class so you can add a private field to count the deep of the directroy.
2. add a `TaskSource<T>` property to the class,  and `await` the  `Task` that generated only if the deep out of the limit, and trigger an event so your UI  can hook into the action and ask user.
3. if user cancel ,  then the `task` fail,  if user confirm, then continue.

some logic code

```
public class FileLocator
{
    public FileLocator(int maxDeep = 6){  
       _maxDeep = maxDeep; 
       this.TaskSource = new TaskSource();
       this.ConfirmTask  = this.TaskSource.Task;
    }
    private int _maxDeep;
    private int _deep;

    public event Action<FileLocator> OnReachMaxDeep;

    public Task ConfirmTask ;
    public TaskSource TaskSource {get;}

    public Task<List<string>> GetFilesRecursivelyAsync()
    {
       var result = new List<string>();
        foreach(xxxxxxx)
        {
            
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
           this._deep +=1;
           if(_deep == _maxDeep)
           {  OnRichMaxDeep?.Invoke(this); }
           if(_deep >= _maxDeep)
           {
              try{
              await ConfirmTask;
              continue;
             }
             catch{
               return result;

            }
           }
        }
    }

}
```

and call

```
var locator = new FileLocator();

locator.OnReachMaxDeep += (x)=> {  var result =  UI.Confirm();  if(result){ x.TaskSource.SetResult(); else{  x.TaskSource.SetException(new Exception())   } }  }


var result = await locator.GetFilesRecursivelyAsync("C:");
```